# Date picker is not working with update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

My application is in asp.net 3.5 in which i am selecting date from date picker which is inside update panel. after selecting date and clicking on submit button page is post back. after post back when i try to select date once again i can`t see date picker there.

//Code on aspx page

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Sample/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UpdateProblem.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sample_UpdateProblem" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>  // Script for date 
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox" CssClass="color" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you must have some initialization script for your datepicker somewhere, so after the postback it is not executed (because it is in an updatepanel).
You need to execute it manually or change the way you set the datepicker. Could you post the code you are actually using please?

Comment: I don't see any datepicker in the code you posted, perhaps you define it somewhere in a js file? (btw I think @Aghilas Yakoub 's answer is what you're looking for;))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your UpdatePanel add css class on your test box

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="classTarget"></asp:TextBox>
           ..... 
        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In your script add this code

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.js">
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

            function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                $('.classTarget).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Add this script <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.js">
    </script>

Comment: And check your css class, if you use color css class, replace in your script

Comment: well it is working absolutely fine but can you explain the code what it is really doing

Comment: why has this line stopped Response.write from working please answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
   bindDatePickers(); // bind date picker on first page load
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindDatePickers); // bind date picker on every UpdatePanel refresh
});

function bindDatePickers() {
   $('#<%= txtInvoiceDateFrom.ClientID%>').datepicker({
      uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4'
   });
   $('#<%= txtInvoiceDateTo.ClientID%>').datepicker({
      uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4'
   });
 }
```