# Date picker not working when dropdownlist index change

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist and textbox in my updatepanel. Namely AuditName, Audit date. The AuditName dropdownlist have the values which are retrieved from database. Audit date is for set the date, here am using jquery datepicker.

The issue is when the page load the date picker is working fine. but when i select the value from dropdown datepicker didnt work(not even display the date).

When i choose the date first then select the dropdown the textbox value is clear. i dont know why its happen..

my code is,

```
<script>
     $(function () {
         $('#<%= txtAuditduedate.ClientID %>').datepicker(
             { minDate: 0, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
     });
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlAddschedule" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%">                   
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAuditlist" Text="Audit Name:/>                            
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddauditlist" TabIndex="100" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="194px"                                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
                        </asp:DropDownList>                            
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDuedate" Text="Audit Due Date:"></asp:Label> 
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAuditduedate" Width="189px" Font-Bold="False" ReadOnly="true" TabIndex="101" />                            
                    </td>
                </tr>                    
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is my dropdown bind code,

```
public void FillDropDownList()
    {
        s = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Scon"].ConnectionString;
        con = new SqlConnection(s);
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select AUDITNAME from MASTER ", con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ddauditlist.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["AUDITNAME"].ToString()));
        }            
        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: show your postback code..

Comment: Set AutoPostBack="False" in your dropdown list ! or remove the update panel and check again

Comment: @RameshRajendran I guess there's a reason he is using an UpdatePanel. This is probably because the date will be dependent on the Dropdown.

Comment: Yes , Now I changed something to my answer !\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try binding the datepicker every time the UpdatePanel is updated.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         bindDatePicker();
         Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindDatePicker);
     });

     function bindDatePicker() {
         $('#<%= txtAuditduedate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
             minDate: 0,
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true
         });
     }    
</script>

<!-- Add the ScriptManager if it doesn't already exist on your page -->
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to load the datepicker on $(document).ready as well.

Comment: Your correct , But why you call the bindDatePicker(); method in above  add_endRequest ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran See Ram's comment. I'm just ensuring that it binds.

Answer (score 1):

add the script behind , that's what I do.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded( $(function () {
     $('#<%= txtAuditduedate.ClientID %>').datepicker(
         { minDate: 0, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
 }););
</script>
```

Sorry for anything syntax was wrong , It's just like a key

See this discussion :

[Date picker is not working with update panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558512/date-picker-is-not-working-with-update-panel)

and see this blog for [jQuery Datepicker does not work after Ajax Partial Postback](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/08/jquery-datepicker-does-not-work-after.html)